# Type attribute with Condition in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

Currently I pass a Type Attribute to a class.

```
public class MyClass<Type> {...}
```

But now I want the condition to exist that the given Type implements an interface.
This is my vain attempt to solve this problem:

```
public class MyClass<Type implements MyInterface> {...}
```

Maybe this helps to understand what I want to achieve.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript these are called [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

This is how you would write it in your case:

```
public class MyClass<Type extends MyInterface> {...}
```